# cannot install ffmpeg - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg but get the message below. How can I fix this ?

```
(base) h@cheemc52:~/opencv/build$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavdevice56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter5 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavformat56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

How do I know which is the correct solution ?

Solution 1

```
(base) h@cheemc52:~$ sudo aptitude install ffmpeg

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libaacplus2{a} libass5{a} libavcodec56{ab} libavdevice56{a} libavfilter5{a} libavformat56{ab} libavresample2{a} libfaac0{a} libfdk-aac1{a}
  libpostproc53{a} libswresample1{a} libutvideo15{a} libvidstab1.0{a} libvo-aacenc0{a} libvo-amrwbenc0{a} libx264-146{a} libx265-51{a}
0 packages upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,543 kB of archives. After unpacking 23.1 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavformat56 : Depends: libgnutls-deb0-28 (>= 3.3.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

 libavcodec56 : Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.3.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     ffmpeg [Not Installed]
2)     libavcodec56 [Not Installed]
3)     libavdevice56 [Not Installed]
4)     libavfilter5 [Not Installed]
5)     libavformat56 [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Solution 2. All other solutions look similar to 2.

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:
1)      ffmpeg [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (xenial-security, xenial-updates)]
2)      libavdevice-ffmpeg56 [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (xenial-security, xenial-updates)]
3)      libavfilter-ffmpeg5 [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (xenial-security, xenial-updates)]
4)      libbs2b0 [3.1.0+dfsg-2.2 (xenial)]
5)      libflite1 [2.0.0-release-1 (xenial)]
6)      libopenal-data [1:1.16.0-3 (now, xenial)]
7)      libopenal1 [1:1.16.0-3 (now, xenial)]
8)      libpostproc-ffmpeg53 [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (xenial-security, xenial-updates)]

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
9)      libavcodec56 [Not Installed]
10)     libavdevice56 [Not Installed]
11)     libavfilter5 [Not Installed]
12)     libavformat56 [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
```

Comment: Which version of Linux and which release number is in use? Different releases have different tools. Please click [edit] and add that to your question; please do not use Add Comment as that's our one-way channel to you.

Comment: @karel i have updated my post